# java script drawing into buffered image

Tags: javascript, image, buffered

I want to draw a bitmap into buffer and create a bitmap using javascript. ideally i should create a bitmap by drawing lines, rectangles and stuffs like that, and paint into the screen when required. Thanks for replying and giving some code hints.

regards

Comment: is there any example in javascript which i can use to create a canvas , draw and scroll from left to right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with canvas:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_graphics_with_canvas